# Какое из этих слов имеет лишь одно значение?

Tags: значение-слов, многозначность

Есть три слова: шотландка, немка, француженка.

Какое из них имеет **лишь одно** значение?

Answer (score 2):

Давайте *разбираться*.

1. Шотландка — это ткань и девушка из Шотландии.

То есть "шотландка" имеет больше чем одно значение.

2. Немка — это девушка из Германии и пушистая оса из отряда перепончатокрылые.

То есть "немка" тоже слово многозначное.

**Вывод:**

> Ответ: француженка.

**НО!**
Есть ещё разговорные значения слов "немка" и "француженка", которые обозначают учителей немецкого и французского соответственно. Но эти слова не являются литературными, и даже несколько грубы, поэтому я эти значения не учитывал.

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, *Зонтик*! Откатили — правьте тогда ещё: фран**з**уженка (в двух местах); "Шотландка" — с маленькой буквы; тире перед тоже не нужно; в конце списка ставится не точка с запятой, а точка. И я с удовольствием поддержу ваш ответ.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова извините, когда откатывал, не совсем понял смысл правки. Сделал откат своего отката.

Comment: И поддержала... Откат отката —  неописуемо! P. S. Если имеете возражения после правок, то "озвучивайте их. Разберемся.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова да, впредь буду действовать более обдуманно =)